# toggle menu not working JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

My website has login system. When `menu` is clicked and the user is not logged in, `showpopup()` function will be called and it will show a sign up form.

When `menu` is clicked and the user is **logged in,** it will show `dropdown` and `afterlogin()` will be called.

the thing is, I would like to toggle `dropdown` when `menu` is clicked. But **once `dropdown` is open, I can close `dropdown` ONLY when I click outside of either `dropdown` or `dropdownA`.**

How do I toggle/ close `dropdown` by clicking `menu`?

**index.php**

```
<div id="menu">Menu</div>

<div id="dropdown"> //this drop down is hidden
    <a href="#" id="a">A</a>
</div>

<div id="dropdownA"> //this drop down is also hidden
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once('database.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo    '1';
return false;
}
if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']))){
    echo    '0';
return false;
}
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

**script.js**

```
$('#menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.post("login.php", function(data) {

        if(data == "1"){
            afterLogin();
            return false;
        } else if(data == "0"){
            showpopup();
            return false;
        }
    });

});

function showpopup()
{//sign up form
 $("#signupForm").fadeIn();
 $("#signupForm").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
}


function afterLogin() {
    $('#menu').on('click', function () {

        $("#dropdown").show(function(){
            document.body.addEventListener('click', boxCloser, false);
        });

    });

    $("#a").click(function() {
        $("#dropdownA").toggle();   
    });

    function boxCloser(e){
      if(!$(e.target).closest('#dropdown, #dropdownA').length){
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', boxCloser, false);
        $('#dropdown, #dropdownA').hide();
      } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Call to functions form`$.post()` done method.

```
$.post("login.php", function(data) {
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data === true){
            afterLogin();

        } else if(data === false){
            showpopup();

        }
    });
```

And In php just return `true` or `false`..

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once('database.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo  true;

}
if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']))){

    echo false;
}
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

For more see docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: is `function(data) { }).done(function(data){` this format a right format? I changed my code according to yours and now it is not showing a `dropdown` menu. it is only refreshing the page.

Comment: I just did and I now understand that .done() is for success. But it still refreshes the page whenever I click on `menu`. it does not call `showpopup()` or `afterlogin()`. So if I use `.done()`, it refreshes the page and does not do anything